# SSIS Performance Issue

Tags: ssis

I'm loading some text files to a SQL Server Database. Each file contains 1000 records and the total number of files is 15.

Problem is each file is taking more than 5 mins time to load.

The files contain 12 columns (String).

I am converting 2 columns into integer using a derived column and the remaining 10 are loading as string

Below is the code used for conversion:

```
  (DT_I4)Mailer_ID
  (DT_I4)Move_Effective_Date
```

I have tried to increase DFT buffer size and using  data conversion in place of the derived column. But the problem still exists.

Comment: Are all the files being loaded to the same table, or does each go to a different table?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what your data flow transformation looks like? Additionally, show us how you have the destination configured.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading directly from source and put into staging, While accessing the data from staging do your transformation.